# Why spatie/laravel-medialibrary raise error on uploding image uploaded with faker-images?

Tags: laravel, faker, laravel-medialibrary

I added https://github.com/morawskim/faker-images to laravel 9 site and when I try get image from this lib
and to upload it with Medialibrary

```
$faker = \Faker\Factory::create();

$faker->addProvider(new \Mmo\Faker\PicsumProvider($faker));
$faker->addProvider(new \Mmo\Faker\LoremSpaceProvider($faker));

 $pageUploadedImageFile= $faker->picsumUrl(400, 400);

$imageMedia = $this->modelItem
     ->addMediaFromUrl($pageUploadedImageFile)
     ->usingFileName($imageFilename)
     ->toMediaCollection('media');
```

where $pageUploadedImageFile has value like :

```
https://picsum.photos/400/400?random=83611
```

which is readable in my browser

But I got error :

```
  Spatie\MediaLibrary\MediaCollections\Exceptions\UnreachableUrl 

  Url `https://picsum.photos/400/400?random=83611` cannot be reached

  at vendor/spatie/laravel-medialibrary/src/MediaCollections/Exceptions/UnreachableUrl.php:9
      5▕ class UnreachableUrl extends FileCannotBeAdded
      6▕ {
      7▕     public static function create(string $url): self
      8▕     {
  ➜   9▕         return new static("Url `{$url}` cannot be reached");
     10▕     }
     11▕ }
     12▕
```

What is wrong and how that can be fixed ?

```
"laravel/framework": "^9.26.1",
"laravel/tinker": "^2.7.2",
"spatie/laravel-medialibrary": "^10.4.4",
"spatie/laravel-permission": "^5.5.5",
"squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "*"

"barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^2.12",
"fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
"laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
"mmo/faker-images": "^0.6.0",
"mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
"nunomaduro/collision": "^6.1",
```

**UPDATED PART :**
I tried to debug source of the package and I found that error israised in
file src/Downloaders/DefaultDownloader.php:

```
<?php

namespace Spatie\MediaLibrary\Downloaders;

use Spatie\MediaLibrary\MediaCollections\Exceptions\UnreachableUrl;

class DefaultDownloader implements Downloader
{
    public function getTempFile(string $url): string
    {
        \Log::info( ' getTempFile $url::');
        \Log::info( $url);
        $stream = fopen($url, 'r');
        \Log::info( ' getTempFile $stream::');
        \Log::info( $stream);
        if (! $stream ) {
            throw UnreachableUrl::create($url);
        }

        $temporaryFile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'media-library');

        file_put_contents($temporaryFile, $stream);

        return $temporaryFile;
    }
}
```

and I see in log

```
[2022-09-29 04:10:51] local.INFO:  getTempFile $url::  
[2022-09-29 04:10:51] local.INFO: https://picsum.photos/800/600?random=86375  
[2022-09-29 04:10:51] local.ERROR: fopen(https://picsum.photos/800/600?random=86375): Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
 {"userId":7,"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): fopen(https://picsum.photos/800/600?random=86375): Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
```

When I copypaste code from https://picsum.photos/800/600?random=86375   into browser I got valid image.
Is it some protection on side of Spatie\MediaLibrary ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I added UPDATED PART

Answer (score 0):

Access restrictions via fopen or curl functions can sometimes be due to user agent restrictions. If you have the ability to modify the source, consider using curl instead of fopen and adding a custom user agent to simulate a browser when fetching files.
Alternatively, you can use the "laravel-image-faker" package as an alternative solution. It can be found at: https://github.com/alirezasedghi/laravel-image-faker